# Exception handling in xml based spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

How to publish exception in error-channel whenever we encounter any exception in any of the route. We dont want to catch exception manually. It should automatically routed to error-channel?

Comment: You need to show your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't go automatically to the `error-channel`. That's not how plain Java works. So, if you call some java code you expect an exception from there and you definitely use a `try...catch` construction.

The `error-channel` makes sense only in the processes not started by end-users, some active processes like task executors and schedulers. For this purpose we indeed provide an `error-channel` hook do not let downstream error to disappear.

Another way to do a-la `try...catch`, but still send to the `error-channel` can be done via Messaging Gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-error-handling. This way the Framework wraps the whole flow to the `try...catch` and sends an `ErrorMessage` to the configured `errorChannel`.

Also for per-service purpose we provide an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its own in-scope `failureChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice